# Scrypt CPU miner supporting segregated witness (for Litecoin testnet4)

Tags: litecoin, testnet, cpu-mining, scrypt, segregated-witness

I am interested in CPU mining on the Litecoin testnet (testnet4); the difficulty level is currently low enough to make this feasible.

The standard Litecoin client no longer supports CPU mining.  The only scrypt CPU miner I'm currently aware of is [Pooler's cpuminer](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer).  However, Litecoin testnet4 has gone to segregated witness, which requires miner client support, and cpuminer doesn't support segwit.

Is there any other CPU mining software that supports this?